# jQuery on change not triggering for select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a select dropdown( location: states ) to which I am appending some options on a response of ajax object.

Now I want to load cities via ajax request on change of state. But, the on change event won't work

I am using below HTML code

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <label>Select state</label><span id="stateLoader"></span>
    <select class="hash-checkout__section-1-add-address-state form-control"></select>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <label>Select city</label><span id="cityLoader"></span>
    <select disabled class="hash-checkout__section-1-add-address-city form-control"></select>
</div>
```

Below ajax response, I am using to append the options to states

```
.done( function( resp ) {
    $( '#stateLoader' ).html( '' );
    $this.attr( 'disabled', false );

    if ( resp.status === 'success' )
        {
            stateDataStatus = true;
            $.each( resp.states , function( index, val ) {
                 $this.append( val );
            });
        }
})
```

Then I am using below code to trigger an onChange event

```
$( 'body' ).on( 'change', '.hash-checkout__section-1-add-address-state', function()
  {
    alert('triggered');
    // $( '#cityLoader' ).html( dataLoader );
  });
```

But for some reason, the on change is not triggering and I am not sure why? why?

Comment: This question could use some focus.  The change event fires when a user selects a value. If your change handler is not firing its likely a selector issue. You should verify your selector actually works.

Comment: when I comment the piece of code where I am appending the ajax response then the on change event works, but as soon as I uncomment it and then just below I have this on change event it doesn't work.

Comment: A few questions. What is $this?  Is it `option` elements that you're appending with `$this.append( val )`; if so, are you really appending them to the select element?

Comment: answer to your question `$( 'body' ).on( 'click focus', '.hash-checkout__section-1-add-address-state', function() { $this = $( this ); });`

Comment: I would suggest you improve the code you've included in order to clarify your question. Help us to help you. ;-)

Comment: "Change" is when you select in a <select> some different value, not the event when you add values to it. Just to be clear, that we all understand the issue correct :) I tried similar to your code, adding options asynchronously and "change" still works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I've tested this arrangement for you:

It's just simple, you should add new val as options using:

```
$this.append( "<option>" + val + "</option>" );
```

HTML index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var stateDataStatus = false;

$(document).ready(function () {

  $( 'body' ).on( 'change', '.hash-checkout__section-1-add-address-state', function()
  {
    alert('triggered');
    // $( '#cityLoader' ).html( dataLoader );
  });

  $( 'body' ).on( 'click focus', '.hash-checkout__section-1-add-address-state', function() {
    //
    // do nothing if having already done:
    //
    if(stateDataStatus) {
        return  false;
    }
    //
    $this = $( this );
    $.ajax({
      url: "getstates.php"
    }).done( function( resp ) {
      //$( '#stateLoader' ).html( '' );
      //$this.attr( 'disabled', false );
      
      //alert(resp);
      
      if ( resp.status === 'success' ) {
        $.each( resp.states , function( index, val ) {
          $this.append( "<option>" + val + "</option>" );
        });
        
        
        stateDataStatus = true;
     
      }
    });
  });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <label>Select state</label><span id="stateLoader"></span>
    <select class="hash-checkout__section-1-add-address-state form-control"></select>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <label>Select city</label><span id="cityLoader"></span>
    <select disabled class="hash-checkout__section-1-add-address-city form-control"></select>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

jQuery.ajax() calls getstates.php that returns just a JSON object like this:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
$array = ["status" => "success", "states" => ["france", "china", "usa"]];
echo json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

[image]

Comment: from backend, i am already passing the `<option></option>` populated with necessary attributes and data. All I am doing is iterating through each array item and appending data.

Comment: No, I am asking in js we are doing the same thing, if it direct send populated array set from backend it should work right?

Comment: For me this is the same... But try we don't know without try...

Comment: not working i have tested from my side as well

Comment: I've tested in Windows Edge,  Google Chrome, all worked. Please test my code both .html and .php...

Comment: Your answer also works. But this worked for me efficiently `$this.prop( 'selectedIndex', 1 ).trigger('change');`

Comment: With $this.prop() you do select a value for the select. Change triggers only when the select.value changes.

Answer (score -1):

Add id's to the select, like this:

```js
//State Select - First Select
$('#stateLoaderSelect').on( 'change', function()
  {
    alert('triggered');
    // $( '#cityLoader' ).html( dataLoader );
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <label>Select state</label><span id="stateLoader"></span>
    <select id="stateLoaderSelect" class="hash-checkout__section-1-add-address-state form-control">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <label>Select city</label><span id="cityLoader"></span>
    <select id="cityLoaderSelect" disabled class="hash-checkout__section-1-add-address-city form-control">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: but why won't it work on BEM optimized class

Comment: Ensure you not have any errors in the console, your posted on('change') works

Comment: I do not have any console errors. I just did some RnD and code worked without IDs as well I added one blank `<option value=''></option>` then appended values to this. It worked as expected.